# How to remove original array elements after mutating changes before writing update

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have a `source.json` that contains playlist entries like so:

```
"playlists" : [
      {
        "id" : "1",
        "owner_id" : "2",
        "song_ids" : [
          "8",
          "32"
        ]
      },
      {
        "id" : "2",
        "owner_id" : "3",
        "song_ids" : [
          "6",
          "8",
          "11"
        ]
      },
      {
        "id" : "3",
        "owner_id" : "7",
        "song_ids" : [
          "7",
          "12",
          "13",
          "16",
          "2"
        ]
      }
    ]
```

and then a `changes.json` file that has updates I want to make to the `source.json` file:

```
{
    "playlists": [{
            "action": "update",
            "payload": [{
                "id": "1",
                "owner_id": "2",
                "song_ids": [
                    "1"
                ]
            }]
        },
        {
            "action": "create",
            "payload": [{
                "id": "1",
                "owner_id": "2",
                "song_ids": [
                    "8",
                    "32"
                ]
            }]
        },
        {
            "action": "delete",
            "payload": [{
                "id": "1"
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

It's a command line program, that in the json contains directives on how to process, i.e. `"action":"update"` and then the `payload` to update with.  After mutating the array, I wish to write out the updated result to `output.json`. I have the code working pretty good, but there is one problem. When it updates it leaves the old entries in the original array. How do you remove those original entries before updating?

Here is my code:

```
    // Stream in source file
    const data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./' + inputFile));

    // Stream in changes file
    const changes = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./' + changesFile));

    for(const [table, actions] of Object.entries(changes)) {
        if(!(table in data))continue;

        // iterate through inner CRUD directives and mutate payloads
        for(const actionDetail of actions) {
            if(actionDetail.action === 'create') {
                console.log('This is a CREATE entry');
                data[table].push(...actionDetail.payload);
            }

            if(actionDetail.action === 'delete') {
                console.log('This is a DELETE entry');
            }

            if(actionDetail.action === 'update') {
                console.log('This is a UPDATE entry');
                
                // const playlistUpdate = get id's from changes.json to update;
                const result = data.playlists.filter(playlist => playlist.id !== playlistUpdate);

                // grr! writes mutation but leaves old entries in original source.json playlist array of objects. grr.
                data[table].push(result);
            }

        }
    }
    fs.writeFileSync('output.json', JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
```

The current `output.json` It doesn't update the `id: 1` with new payload, it concatenates. grr.

```
"playlists": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "owner_id": "2",
      "song_ids": [
        "8",
        "32"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "owner_id": "3",
      "song_ids": [
        "6",
        "8",
        "11"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "owner_id": "7",
      "song_ids": [
        "7",
        "12",
        "13",
        "16",
        "2"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "owner_id": "2",
      "song_ids": [
        "1"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
...
if(actionDetail.action === 'update') {

 // const playlistUpdate = get id's from changes.json to update;
 const playlists = data.playlists.map(function updateCallback(playlist) {
  if(playlistUpdate.indexOf(playlist.id) === -1) {
    return playlist; // if not required to update, return original
  }
  // Modify the playlist based on the update & return the same.
  return modifiedVersion;
 });
 data[table] = playlists;
}
...
```

**Update:**

I am not able to understand your problem correctly. So, I put together as scenario similar to yours.

If simply want to update the array elements, you can do something like this:

Assume this is the array that we have(similar to your `source.json`):

```
[{
  id: 1,
  firstName: 'A',
  lastName: 'a'
}, {
  id: 2,
  firstName: 'B',
  lastName: 'b'
}, {
  id: 3,
  firstName: 'C',
  lastName: 'c'
}, {
  id: 4,
  firstName: 'D',
  lastName: 'd'
}]
```

Now, let say, I want to update the above array with elements id 2 & 3. Check the following data(similar to update.json)

```
[{
  id: 2,
  firstName: 'BB',
  lastName: 'bb'
}, {
  id: 3,
  firstName: 'CC',
  lastName: 'cc'
}]
```

Once the update is applied, I want the result to be like follows:

```
[{
  id: 1,
  firstName: 'A',
  lastName: 'a'
}, {
  id: 2,
  firstName: 'BB',
  lastName: 'bb'
}, {
  id: 3,
  firstName: 'CC',
  lastName: 'cc'
}, {
  id: 4,
  firstName: 'D',
  lastName: 'd'
}]
```

If so, I can do this:

```
const sourceArray = [{
  id: 1,
  firstName: 'A',
  lastName: 'a'
}, {
  id: 2,
  firstName: 'B',
  lastName: 'b'
}, {
  id: 3,
  firstName: 'C',
  lastName: 'c'
}, {
  id: 4,
  firstName: 'D',
  lastName: 'd'
}]; // loaded from source.json

const updateArray = [{
  id: 2,
  firstName: 'BB',
  lastName: 'bb'
}, {
  id: 3,
  firstName: 'CC',
  lastName: 'cc'
}]; // loaded from update.json

function applyUpdates(source, update) {

  // iterate through source
  for (let element of source) {

    // for every element in source, iterate through update
    for (let updateElement of update) {

      // if source element is not same as update element, move to next "update" element
      if (element.id !== updateElement.id) {
        continue;
      }

      // if source element is same as update element, apply updates
      element.firstName = updateElement.firstName;
      element.lastName = updateElement.lastName;

      // move to next "source" element
      break;

    }

  }

}

applyUpdates(sourceArray, update);

console.log(source); // now source will have the updated data
```

Comment: I already do not know the answer. Wrapping that unknowing in a callback doesn't arrive at the solution. Only compounds the obfuscation of the problem. Thanks

Comment: @Rachel, check the update!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you can do

```
const fs = require('fs')    
    
    // Stream in source file
    const data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./source.json'));

    // Stream in changes file
    const changes = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./changes.json'));


    for(const [table, actions] of Object.entries(changes)) {
        if(!(table in data))continue;

        // iterate through inner CRUD directives and mutate payloads
        for(const actionDetail of actions) {
            // if(actionDetail.action === 'create') {
            //     console.log('This is a CREATE entry');
            //     data[table].push(...actionDetail.payload);
            // }

            // if(actionDetail.action === 'delete') {
            //     console.log('This is a DELETE entry');
            // }

            if(actionDetail.action === 'update') {
                console.log('This is a UPDATE entry');
                
                // const playlistUpdate = get id's from changes.json to update;
                const result = data.playlists.map(playlist => {
                    if(playlist.id !== actionDetail.payload[0].id){
                        return playlist
                    }else {
                        playlist.song_ids = [].concat(actionDetail.payload[0].song_ids)
                        return playlist
                    }
                });

                // data[table].push(result);
                data.playlists.concat(result)
            }

        }
    }
    fs.writeFileSync('output.json', JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
```

Basically .map .filter wont mutate original array

Comment: Doesn't work. Just concatenates update as a new entry and does not remove original.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that apparently you can use olap cube js :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/olap-cube-js
to maybe have faster issue i think

I hope I understood your idea and help